# What is the best way to load Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, assembly-references

I want to know what is the best way to load Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell assembly in Powershell IDE.

Because I looked many variations on the internet(ect. google).

**First option:**

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

**Second option:**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

***Best option is?***

Answer (score 1):

First option is best way to load the power-shell libraries. as second option was in SharePoint 2007 but after SharePoint 2010 Microsoft introduce the snap-ins which reduces the number of lines to load the power-shell assemblies.

[you can find more info here](http://www.itprotoday.com/powershell-and-sharepoint-step-1-loading-dlls-and-snap-ins)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in SharePoint 2010 and above is:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
```

This will ignore errors if the snaphin is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is add it to your profile. Follow these steps

- Open up PowerShell ISE and run the following to create a profile
  script if one doesn’t exist and edit it in the ISE:

> ```
> if (!(test-path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts)) {new-item -type file -path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts –force}
>
> powershell_ise $profile.AllUsersAllHosts
> ```

- That will open a new tab in PowerShell ISE allowing you to edit profile.ps1
- In PowerShell ISE, you will now have a new tab where you can edit this file.  In that new tab, add the following code and then save the file.

  $ver = $host | select version

  ```
   if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 

   if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 

   {

       Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

   }
  ```
- Now, close PowerShell ISE and then open it again.

Please read complete details here: [Add Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell Snap-In to All PowerShell Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/11/14/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

For the two options you specified, both would work. But I will choose the first one, because it will first check if the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell has been loaded, if not then use Add-PSSnapin command to add, it is more suitable with logic side and better.

Answer (score 0):

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"